# Keras ValueError: Paddings must be non-negative

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am trying to use the TokenAndPositionEmbedding layer inside my Keras model:

```py
concatenate = keras.layers.concatenate(input_layers, axis=1)

# Batch size is 32, so the concatenate layer ouput shape is (32, 2400) because it concatenates 4 inputs of shape (32, 600)

x = keras_nlp.layers.TokenAndPositionEmbedding(
    vocabulary_size=20000,
    sequence_length=600,
    embedding_dim=256,
    mask_zero=True,
)(x)
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: Paddings must be non-negative for '{{node gradient_tape/model_12/token_and_position_embedding_10/position_embedding11/Pad}} = Pad[T=DT_FLOAT, Tpaddings=DT_INT32 (gradient_tape/model_12/token_and_position_embedding_10/position_embedding11/Reshape, gradient_tape/model_12/token_and_position_embedding_10/position_embedding11/concat)' with input shapes: [2400,256], [2,2] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <[0 -1800][0 0]>.
```

Note that I have tried to use the Embedding layer alone and the Position Embedding layer alone too. The error comes from the Position Embedding layer.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am not sure about this, but have you tried changing the `sequence_length` to `2400`?

Comment: This was the problem! Thanks